# Hibernate GeneratedValue and Id from UI

Tags: hibernate

```
accountDetails.setAccountsId(Long.parseLong(account.getId()));
System.out.println("accountDetails.accoundId-->"+accountDetails.getAccountsId());
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Query query = session.createQuery("from QBAccounts qba where qba.accountsId=:accId");
List<AccountDetails> queryList = query.setParameter("accId", accountDetails.getAccountsId()).list();
session.close();
Session session2 = sessionFactory.openSession();
//          session.saveOrUpdate(accountDetails);
try{
    if(queryList.size()>0){
        session2 = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session2.beginTransaction();
        session2.update(accountDetails);
    } else{
        session2.beginTransaction();
        session2.save(accountDetails);
    }
```

DTO:

```
@Entity(name="QBAccounts")
@Table(name="sias_account")
public class AccountDetails implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "accounts_id")
  private Long accountsId;

  @Column(name = "subaccount")
  private String subAccount;
```

SQL Query:

```
create table sias_account (accounts_id number(20), subaccount varchar(100))
```

Output:

accountDetails.accoundId-->53

But when I see in my oracle db table, it prints sequence number i.e increment always instead of printing exact accounts_id from UI to table.

Data in table now is: 2305 and it keeps incrementing.

Comment: `But when I see in my oracle db table, it prints sequence number i.e increment always instead of printing exact accounts_id from UI to table.` What do you mean by that? can you elaborate, what sequence you are referring to? Also the query is on `QBAccounts` , is that correct? Also what do you mean by this `Data in table now is: 2305 and it keeps incrementing. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  @Id
  @Column(name = "accounts_id")
  private Long accountsId;
```

If ids are provided from UI then you don't need @GeneratedValue at all as there is no id to generate.

Comment: I didn't understand the conditions